# How do I resolve "Files is not responding" in GNOME Files?

Tags: filemanager

I tried to open other applications.  Some are working and some are not. My settings options are also giving the error "not responding".

Please help I don't want to lose my files in my PC.

[image: photo of screen showing Gnome Files "Files" is not responding"]

[image: screenshot of error messages]

Comment: My setting option is also saying the same thing not responding

Comment: What other software is not working properly?  Have you tried to reboot the computer?  Are you trying to move/copy/relocate a large file or a large number of files? When you say "setting option", do you mean that your system settings application is not working?  Could it be possible that your hard drive is failing or that you have some other hardware problem?  As a diagnostic step, please boot a live session of Ubuntu from installation media (Try Ubuntu).  Tell us if the problem persists in the live session. This would be a good time to backup if your backups are deficient.

Comment: I have tried to reboot the computer but it waits 120 sec and fails .

Comment: I have open builder in ubuntu and it opens my python files and text files. But I cannot open visual studio code and settings

Comment: I have updated the ubuntu today. After restarting the system my problem is occuring

Comment: And I haven't move  large files as  I only use zoom and google

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1357427/edit) your question and include any extra details so that anyone new visiting this question does not have to read comment chains to get all of the information about your question.  It seems your problem is more widespread than the question you have asked because the problem is not unique to GNOME files.  You still have not run a live session.  Please do this before responding so you can update your question to let us know if the problems persist in a live session.

Comment: Do you have a USB disk or flash drive plugged in? It looks like it may have an error condition. Unplug it and see if things improve. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I am trying to say is there was a option to update ubuntu base and after I restart my pc it suddenly freezes at file . I have tried many times and restarted it but it say error and waiting 120 sec

Comment: I was using usb flash after this issue if there  is a possibility to tranfer the files

Comment: What is the EXACT error message that you see? It may be related to the USB device that I see. Reminder.... start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Please see the error message

Comment: Did you unplug the possible USB device that may be causing an error? **Please pay attention to instructions**. Also... third reminder... start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema please see I have provided the new image error

Comment: Yes, I saw the error. Thanks. 45 minutes ago, and 20 minutes ago, I asked you to unplug your USB device that may be causing a problem. If you can't do that, then I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema please see I have removed the usb ( pendrive and a charger usb foe mobile

Comment: Did you reboot to see if you still have the error message at boot time, and problem with the `Disks` application? Do you have access to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: @JoyeshSantra Status please...

Comment: @JoyeshSantra Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at your dock, you have a USB device in an error condition. It maybe a USB disk, printer, or flash key. Remove the device, reboot, and see if you still have boot-time error messages, and if `Disks` works now.

Let's check your filesystem...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`